# command with exec and tee to redirect output to a file and console at the same time

Tags: linux, exec, tee

Linux script has the command `exec > &LOGFILE 2>&1` to redirect output to a file, I am trying to amend the command to redirect output to a file and also to the console at the same time.

None of the below command works. It either redirects output to file or writes to the console but not both at the same time. Can somebody help?

```
exec > >(tee -a $LOGFILE) 2>&1

exec &> >(tee -a $LOGFILE) 2>&1

exec >> $LOGFILE 2>&1 && tail -f $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Your first example works in bash.  Perhaps you want `exec > >(tee -a ${LOGFILE?}) 2>&1` to catch the error when LOGFILE is undefined.

Comment: include a tag for the shell you are using, usually (and hopefully) `[bash]`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks William and Shelter. As said the command "exec > >(tee -a $LOGFILE) 2>&1" works in bash. All my script runs in korn and I cant change it to bash for this command alone to work. is there a way to achieve this in korn?